# printing via Bluetooth from mobile device to zebra printer

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, zebra-printers

I want to print a receipt containing text from MC75 [Windows mobile 6] and using a bluetooth printer (Zebra ).

I am very new to windows mobile and I don't know where to start and how to connect with bluetooth devices.

Please can someone provide me with some link or code to start with a print "hello world" via a bluetooth printer in c#.

Answer (score 0):

You may use my btComPrint as starting point: https://github.com/hjgode/btComPrint

In general you can use a BT printer via a BT socket (similar to TCP/IP socket). OpenNetCF offers some helper in there framework.

Or you use simply a BT paired printer's virtual COM port (see RegisterDevice, or use BT applet in Windows Mobile and then define an outgoing port for SPP of BT printer).

You may also go with PrinterCE SDK and let this connect to the printer and use the PrinterCE SDK to print.

Zebra also offers some SDK, see there home page.

If you have a connection, a BT socket or virtual COM port, you simply send the printer commands (CPCL or ZPL printer language commands) to let the printer print.